# Not getting dojo circular dependency error as per tutorial

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am following dojo tutorial [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules_advanced/). As per tutorial I should get error but I am getting the output without any error. Am I missing something? Below is my code.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
    var dojoConfig = {
        baseUrl : "js/",
        tlmSiblingOfDojo : false,
        packages : [
            {name : "dojo", location : "lib/dojo"},
            {name : "dijit", location : "lib/dijit"},
            {name : "dojox", location : "lib/dojox"},
            {name : "my", location : "my", main:"moduleA"}
        ]
    }
</script>
<script src="js/lib/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
<script>
    require([
            "my/ModuleA"
    ], function(moduleA){
        moduleA.print();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**moduleA**

```
define([ "./moduleB" ], function(moduleB){
    return {
        getValue: function(){
            return "oranges";
        },

        print: function(){
            console.log(moduleB.getValue());
        }
    };
});
```

**moduleB**

```
define([ "./moduleA" ], function(moduleA){
    return {
        getValue: function(){
            return "apples and " + moduleA.getValue();
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my/moduleA` and `my/ModuleA` are two different modules. You haven’t created a circular dependency, you’ve just leveraged a feature/defect of case-insensitive filesystems to load two different copies of the same code with different module IDs.

Comment: Ohh I didn't see that and after making it lowercase it's giving error now.